# Enumerating the Writing of Different Lines in Txt file in Python

Tags: python, enumerate

It seems that every time the string should add up the 4, 1, and 4, for column 1, the total result is just 4*3.

Could you help me put an enumeration-like function in here? (I am I very new beginner)

Thank you for anything!

```
 import os
 import platform
 
 pathwindows = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + r"\Documents\Your_Wordle_Results.txt"
 pathmac = r'/Mac/Users/%USEPROFILE%/Documents/Your_Wordle_Results.txt'
 isFileWindows = os.path.exists(pathwindows)
 isFileMac = os.path.isfile(pathmac)
 
 if isFileWindows == True:
 outfile = open(pathwindows, 'r')
 
 if isFileMac == True:
 outfile = open(pathmac, 'r')
 
 totalpoints1 = 0
 totalpoints2 = 0
 totalpoints3 = 0
 totalpoints4 = 0
 totalpoints5 = 0
 
 with open(pathwindows, 'r') as fp:
 
 lineofinterest = fp.readlines()[2:100]
 stringlineofinterest = str(lineofinterest)
 print(*lineofinterest)
 for line in lineofinterest:
 print(line.strip())
 
 startline = 22
 separation = 4
 value1 = (stringlineofinterest[startline + separation * 0])
 value2 = (stringlineofinterest[startline + separation * 1])
 value3 = (stringlineofinterest[startline + separation * 2])
 value4 = (stringlineofinterest[startline + separation * 3])
 value5 = (stringlineofinterest[startline + separation * 4])
 
 outfile.close   
 
 print(value1)
 
 print(totalpoints1)
```

The text file is

```
Ben        Jackson    
                    1pt 2pt 3pt 4pt 5pt                    Total Results Will Be Shown Below
                    4   3   0   1   0   LOSS for audio in 7.28s
                    1   2   0   2   0   LOSS for audit in 6.18s
                    4   5   0   1   0   LOSS for audio in 7.28s
```

I expected for the 4 + 1 +4 to add up in the 1 pt column but rather the first "4" was multiplied 3 times meaning that the cycle that beings with "with open" did not enumerate through.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this the best I can according to the post, there was problems with indentation, use of the correct variable to fetch the values (stringlineofinteres instead of line which is the one in the loop), your code, and finally no line to add vaalues to the totals:

```
import os
import platform

pathwindows = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + r"\Documents\Your_Wordle_Results.txt"
pathmac = r'/Mac/Users/%USEPROFILE%/Documents/Your_Wordle_Results.txt'

pathwindows="enum.txt"

isFileWindows = os.path.exists(pathwindows)
isFileMac = os.path.isfile(pathmac)

if isFileWindows == True:
    filepath=pathwindows
 
if isFileMac == True:
    filepath=pathmac
    

totalpoints1 = 0
totalpoints2 = 0
totalpoints3 = 0
totalpoints4 = 0
totalpoints5 = 0

with open(filepath, 'r') as fp:

    lineofinterest = fp.readlines()[2:100]
    stringlineofinterest = str(lineofinterest)
    print(*lineofinterest)
    for line in lineofinterest:
        print(line)

        startline = 22
        separation = 4
        value1 = (line[startline + separation * 0])
        totalpoints1 += int(value1)
        value2 = (line[startline + separation * 1])
        totalpoints2 += int(value2)
        value3 = (line[startline + separation * 2])
        totalpoints3 += int(value3)
        value4 = (line[startline + separation * 3])
        totalpoints4 += int(value4)
        value5 = (line[startline + separation * 4])
        totalpoints5 += int(value5)


# write the totals line here
with open(filepath,'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write("totals    xxxx")


print(totalpoints1, totalpoints2,totalpoints3,totalpoints4,totalpoints5)
```